# Using BeautifulSoup to Download Links From A WebPage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, python-requests

I wrote a function to find all .pdf files from a web-page & download them. It works well when the link is publicly accessible but when I use it for a course website (which can only be accessed on my university's internet), the pdfs downloaded are corrupted and cannot be opened.

How can I fix it?

```
def get_pdfs(my_url):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(my_url).read()
    html_page = BeautifulSoup(html)
    current_link = ''
    links = []
    for link in html_page.find_all('a'):
        current_link = link.get('href')
        if current_link.endswith('pdf'):
            links.append(my_url + current_link)
    print(links)

    for link in links:
        #urlretrieve(link)
        wget.download(link)

get_pdfs('https://grader.eecs.jacobs-university.de/courses/320241/2019_2/')
```

When I use this grader link, the current_link is something like `/courses/320241/2019_2/lectures/lecture_7_8.pdf` but the `/courses/320241/2019_2/` part is already included in the my_url and when I append it, it obviously doesn't work. However, the function works perfectly for [this link][1]:

Is there a way I can use the same function to work with both types of links?

Comment: The `href` attributes are containing only relative URIs, eg. `<a href="p1.pdf">Sheet #1</a>` so you need to add base URI to it, eg. `links.append(my_url + current_link)`

Comment: Can you give an example of `current_link`?

Comment: @JackFleeting I now see the problem. For this particular my_url, the current link is ```/courses/320241/2019_2/lectures/lecture_7_8.pdf``` but the ```/courses/320241/2019_2/``` part is already in my_url & I'm appending it again. However, the program works for this link: https://cnds.jacobs-university.de/courses/os-2019/ perfectly. Is there a way I can make it run for both?

Comment: Are you sure that the `current_link` example from the `my_url` that doesn't work is exactly  `/courses/320241/2019_2/lectures/lecture_7_8.pdf`? If so, there must be something else on that page that resolves urls. But since it requires login, I won't be able to see it.

Comment: @JackFleeting Yup, that's the link. If I just try downloading this entire link with wget, it works perfectly: ```https://grader.eecs.jacobs-university.de/courses/320241/2019_2/lectures/lecture_7_8.pdf``` but I need a way where I can look in ```my_url``` and see if a part of the string is matching. If it is, I want to remove the matching part and concatenate the rest to open the link

Comment: In that case, as I said, we will need to see the html source code for https://grader.eecs.jacobs-university.de/courses/320241/2019_2...

Comment: @JackFleeting I updated the question after printing the html_page

Comment: See (attempted) answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I understand the issue now. Try the code below on your data. I *think* it works, but obviously I couldn't try it directly on the page requiring login. Also, I changed your structure and variable definitions a bit, because I find it easier to think that way, but if it works, you can easily modify it to suit your own tastes.

Anyway, here goes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urlparse

my_urls = ['https://cnds.jacobs-university.de/courses/os-2019/', 'https://grader.eecs.jacobs-university.de/courses/320241/2019_2']
links = []
for url in my_urls:    
    resp = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(resp.text,'lxml')
    og = soup.find("meta",  property="og:url")
    base = urlparse(url)
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        current_link = link.get('href')
        if current_link.endswith('pdf'):
            if og:
                links.append(og["content"] + current_link)
            else:
                links.append(base.scheme+"://"+base.netloc + current_link)
for link in links:
    print(link)
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly! And I also understood the og logic you used for two different websites. Hadn't thought about it before. Thank you!